# to group my results by varying distances from an object

Tags: postgresql, distance

I created a successful query that counts the number of objects + average the prices of the counted objects. the query looks like this:

```
select count (product_id), avg (price)
from current_table
```

Now, I want to group the results by DISTANCE column that is already exist in the table BUT IN PARTICULAR DISTANCE GROUPING like this:
groups of 0-10 km, 10-20 km, 20-30 km etc. lets say about 10 different distance groups.

How can I do it?

thanks!!!!

Comment: `GROUP BY distance/10`